# Why does upcast to parent abstract class not work

Tags: java, oop

In JAVA we can create an interface reference and provide it a child class object but why can't we do the same with abstract class?

```
public abstract class Hello {
    public abstract void m1();
}

public class Demo extends Hello {
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello h = new Demo();// why this approach is wrong
        h.m1();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not wrong. What error are you getting?

Comment: You can; why do you think you can't?

Comment: That code is completely fine and I dont see any issue with what you are describing. Voting to close, cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Perfectly fine. Everything will work same as Interface example you have talked about.

Comment: I thought it will not work.
Thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 2):

> but why can't we do the same with abstract class?

You can do it with abstract class.
The code you provided should work.